# On Resend OTP receiving same OTP so cant understand when the OTP gets expires using firebase OTP or why its same on resend also

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

this is the function used when the first time requesting OTP..

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNumber: "+$countryCode ${phoneController.text}.",
                        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
                          otpValue = credential.smsCode.toString();
                          showLoading = false;
                        },
                        verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) {
                          setState(() {
                            showLoading = false;
                            switch (verificationFailed.code) {
                              case "invalid-phone-number":
                                phoneError = "Please Enter valid phone number";
                                print("invalid-phone-number");
                                break;

                              case "too-many-requests":
                                phoneError = "too many requests,\nPlease try again after some time";
                                print("too many attempts");
                                break;
                            }
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          });
                          print(verificationFailed.code);
                        },
                        codeSent: (verificationID, resendingToken) async {
                          setState(() {
                            showLoading = false;
                            // _isButtonDisabled = true;
                            print("check here");
                            this.verificationID = verificationID;
                            _resendToken = resendingToken;
                            Navigator.pop(context);//loading close
                            nextButtonLoginEnable = true;
                            print("check here 1");
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => OTPWidget(
                                  number: phoneController.text,
                                  verificationId: verificationID,
                                  countryCode: countryCode,
                                  resendToken: _resendToken,
                                  smsCode: otpValue,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                        },
                        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationID) async {});}
```

Second is the top page where I check the OTP

```
if (otpController.text == "") {
                        print("is it in if");
                        setState(() {
                          otpErrorText = "Please enter OTP";
                        });
                      }
                      else if (otpController.text.length < 4) {
                        print("is it in else if");
                        setState(() {
                          otpErrorText = "Please enter 6 digit OTP number";
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          otpErrorText = "";
                          loaderforNavigate();
                        });
                        AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
                        PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                            verificationId: widget.verificationId ?? "",
                            smsCode: otpController.text);}
```

but if user didn't receive then giving the option to resend..

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
                                    phoneNumber:
                                        "+${widget.countryCode}${widget.number}.",
                                    verificationCompleted:
                                        (phoneAuthCredential) async {
                                      showLoading = false;
                                    },
                                    verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showLoading = false;
                                      });
                                      print(verificationFailed.code);
                                    },
                                    forceResendingToken: widget.resendToken,
                                    codeSent: (verificationID, resendingToken) async {
                                      setState(() {
                                        showLoading = false;
                                        _isButtonDisabled = true;
                                        //currentState = LoginScreen.SHOW_OTP_FORM_WIDGET;
                                        this.verificationID = verificationID;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout:
                                        (verificationID) async {});}
```

When clicking on resend OTP for requesting again then still receives the same OTP as get before so cand decide whether its expiring or not or why getting same one always until clearing the cache. please help

Answer (score 0):

Firebase sends 3 times same SMS code and then changes them to a different one.